# Let $G$ be a finite group and $g \in G$. Then the order of $g$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $g \in G$. Then the order of $g$ is finite.

I know that  if $g$ has finite order, then $g^k = e$ for a finite $k$, but i'm not really sure how to get started showing this. Since there is a finite number of elements in $G$, it makes intuitive sense that this result should be true.

Comment: Consider the sequence $\{g^0,g^1,g^2,g^3,\cdots\}$. Can this subset of $G$, a finite group, be infinitely many distinct elements?

Comment: I think it's intuitive that the order, if it exists, it is finite. What I don't think is as intuitive is that an order necessarily exists.

Comment: I suggest that you use Proof by Contradiction technique, i.e. assume that order of any element of the group $G$ is infinite. See what this assumption implies.

Comment: The order always exists. If it's infinite then it exists: it's just infinite.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336812

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: consider the infinite sequence of elements $g,g^2,g^3\dots$. It must contain repeated elements $g^l=g^k$ for $l<k$. So we have $eg^l=g^{k-l}g^l$, what can we conclude about $g^{k-l}$ if we use the cancellation law?